# Error while parsing XML using Java

Tags: java, xml, parsing

I am trying to parse A xml document which I have obtained from Google Geocode Api .

My XML File. I have a series of such data in the Same file. this is just one node

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<GeocodeResponse>
<status>OK</status>
 <result>
  <formatted_address>Petroleum House, Jamshedji Tata Road, Churchgate, Mumbai, Maharashtra 400020, India</formatted_address>
  <address_component>
<long_name>Petroleum House</long_name>
<short_name>Petroleum House</short_name>
</address_component>
<address_component>
<long_name>Jamshedji Tata Road</long_name>
<short_name>Jamshedji Tata Road</short_name>
<type>route</type>
</address_component>
<address_component>
<long_name>Churchgate</long_name>
<short_name>Churchgate</short_name>
<type>sublocality</type>
<type>political</type>
</address_component>
<address_component>
<long_name>Mumbai</long_name>
<short_name>मॿंबई</short_name>
<type>locality</type>
<type>political</type>
</address_component>
<address_component>
<long_name>Mumbai</long_name>
<short_name>Mumbai</short_name>
<type>administrative_area_level_2</type>
<type>political</type>
</address_component>
<address_component>
<long_name>Maharashtra</long_name>
<short_name>MH</short_name>
<type>administrative_area_level_1</type>
<type>political</type>
</address_component>
<address_component>
<long_name>India</long_name>
<short_name>IN</short_name>
<type>country</type>
<type>political</type>
</address_component>
<address_component>
<long_name>400020</long_name>
<short_name>400020</short_name>
<type>postal_code</type>
</address_component>
<geometry>
<location>
<lat>18.9291061</lat>
<lng>72.8255146</lng>
</location>
<location_type>APPROXIMATE</location_type>
<viewport>
<southwest>
<lat>18.9277189</lat>
<lng>72.8240293</lng>
</southwest>
<northeast>
<lat>18.9304168</lat>
<lng>72.8267272</lng>
</northeast>
</viewport>
<bounds>
<southwest>
<lat>18.9288559</lat>
<lng>72.8251686</lng>
</southwest>
<northeast>
<lat>18.9292798</lat>
<lng>72.8255879</lng>
</northeast>
</bounds>
</geometry>
</result>
</GeocodeResponse>
```

I am trying to use the following code but I am getting some error.This is the first time me trying to parse an XML.

```
import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

public class parser {

public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {

        File stocks = new File("filename.xml");
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory
                .newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = dBuilder.parse(stocks);
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

        System.out.println("root of xml file"
                + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());
        NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("address_component");
        System.out.println("==========================");

        for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
            Node node = nodes.item(i);

            if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                Element element = (Element) node;
                System.out.println("Name: "
                        + getValue("long_name", element));
                System.out.println("lat: " + getValue("lat", element));
                System.out.println("lon: " + getValue("lon", element));
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private static String getValue(String tag, Element element) {
    NodeList nodes = element.getElementsByTagName(tag).item(0)
            .getChildNodes();
    Node node = (Node) nodes.item(0);
    return node.getNodeValue();
}
```

``     }

The error I am getting

```
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.io.MalformedByteSequenceException: Invalid byte 3 of 3-byte UTF-8 sequence.
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.io.UTF8Reader.invalidByte(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.io.UTF8Reader.read(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityScanner.load(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityScanner.scanContent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(Unknown Source)
at parser.main(parser.java:17)
```

Direct Ouput from Google

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<GeocodeResponse>
<status>OK</status>
<result>
<formatted_address>Petroleum House, Jamshedji Tata Road, Churchgate, Mumbai, Maharashtra 400020, India</formatted_address>
<address_component>
<long_name>Petroleum House</long_name>
<short_name>Petroleum House</short_name>
</address_component>
<address_component>
<long_name>Jamshedji Tata Road</long_name>
<short_name>Jamshedji Tata Road</short_name>
<type>route</type>
</address_component>
<address_component>
<long_name>Churchgate</long_name>
<short_name>Churchgate</short_name>
<type>sublocality</type>
<type>political</type>
</address_component>
<address_component>
<long_name>Mumbai</long_name>
<short_name>à¤®à¥?à¤‚à¤¬à¤ˆ</short_name>
<type>locality</type>
<type>political</type>
</address_component>
<address_component>
<long_name>Mumbai</long_name>
<short_name>Mumbai</short_name>
<type>administrative_area_level_2</type>
<type>political</type>
</address_component>
<address_component>
<long_name>Maharashtra</long_name>
<short_name>MH</short_name>
<type>administrative_area_level_1</type>
<type>political</type>
</address_component>
<address_component>
<long_name>India</long_name>
<short_name>IN</short_name>
<type>country</type>
<type>political</type>
</address_component>
<address_component>
<long_name>400020</long_name>
<short_name>400020</short_name>
<type>postal_code</type>
</address_component>
<geometry>
<location>
<lat>18.9291061</lat>
<lng>72.8255146</lng>
</location>
<location_type>APPROXIMATE</location_type>
<viewport>
<southwest>
<lat>18.9277189</lat>
<lng>72.8240293</lng>
</southwest>
<northeast>
<lat>18.9304168</lat>
<lng>72.8267272</lng>
</northeast>
</viewport>
<bounds>
<southwest>
<lat>18.9288559</lat>
<lng>72.8251686</lng>
</southwest>
<northeast>
<lat>18.9292798</lat>
<lng>72.8255879</lng>
</northeast>
</bounds>
</geometry>
</result>
</GeocodeResponse>
```

This is the direct output from google

Comment: Seems like `File stocks = new File("filename.xml");` does not load file

Comment: That line *doesn't* load a file. It merely declares a File object.

Comment: ... and that line works since he is not getting a `FileNotFoundException`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say it has to do with the file encoding.
If you are on a windows machine it could translate the xml file as the windows ISO format instead of UTF-8

I would try to replace the

```
Document doc = dBuilder.parse(stocks);
```

with:

```
Document doc = dBuilder.parse(new FileInputStream(stocks), "UTF8")));
```

To make sure the input file is read as UTF-8

Edit:
How to check the files encoding with notepad++

[image: Notepad++ encoding check]

Comment: and as Brian Agnew mentiones, make sure the input file is really UTF-8.

Comment: The data which I have received is directly from google services and is just stored in a file.

Comment: If you open the file with a text editor (like notepad++) what kind of encoding does it say the file has? ( http://npp-community.tuxfamily.org/documentation/notepad-user-manual/document-properties/encoding )

Comment: I am using NP++ only to view the data and it is properly showing <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

Comment: that part only says the encodign of the XML not the File itself. a slight difference. I edited my original post and added how to see the file encoding.

Comment: I was able to delete some Corrupted data and now i got a well functioning xml file

Answer (score 3):

I suspect the file has been misencoded whilst being saved.

Your file says UTF-8 at the top, but whatever has saved it *hasn't* saved it as UTF-8. You should be able to confirm this by viewing via another XML-capable tool e.g. a browser or perhaps a command-line tool such as [XMLStarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/).

Can you get that input direct from the Google service ? i.e. don't save it as an intermediate file. That would be worth doing if only to confirm this issue.

Comment: I have added the direct output from Google Service

Comment: Note that if you *write* that output to a file, that writing must be UTF-8 aware. If you load it into an editor and then write it out, that *editor* must preserve the encoding. Basically everything in your transformation chain has to be UTF-8 aware. I would use an independent tool such as XMLStarlet to check at each stage that corruption hasn't occurred

Answer (score 0):

You can try to parse your file like this:

```
File file = new File("filename.xml");
InputStream inputStream= new FileInputStream(file);
Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"UTF-8");
InputSource is = new InputSource(reader);
is.setEncoding("UTF-8");
Document doc = dBuilder.parse(is);
```

That's just a wild guess tho...

Comment: I tried your code ..I am getting the following Error [Fatal Error] :80:2: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 80; columnNumber: 2; The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
 at parser.main(parser.java:27)